# How can I have a live timer that updates every seconds within a 3 second loop?

Tags: javascript

I'm using some code like this
    window.setInterval(function(){
    //Code goes here
    }, 3000);
for a 3 seconds loop, and I want to have a timer counting up within that that updates every seconds instead of every 3 seconds, is that possible?

I tried putting this in the loop:

```
var stmints = 0;
var stseconds = 0;
var stzecsec = 0;


function toAutoStop() {
  alert('Your life goes on');
}


var zecsec = 0;
var seconds = 0;
var mints = 0;

var startchron = 0;

function chronometer() {
  if(startchron == 1) {
    zecsec += 1;       // set tenths of a second


    if(zecsec > 9) {
      zecsec = 0;
      seconds += 1;
    }


    if(seconds > 59) {
      seconds = 0;
      mints += 1;
    }


   document.getElementById('showtm').innerHTML = mints+ ' : '+ seconds+ '<sub>'+ zecsec+             '</sub>';


    if(zecsec == stzecsec && seconds == stseconds && mints == stmints) toAutoStop();
    else setTimeout("chronometer()", 100);
  }
}

function startChr() { startchron = 1; chronometer(); }      // starts the chronometer
function stopChr() { startchron = 0; }                      // stops the chronometer
function resetChr() {
  zecsec = 0;  seconds = 0; mints = 0; startchron = 0;
  document.getElementById('showtm').innerHTML = mints+ ' : '+ seconds+ '<sub>'+ zecsec+     '</sub>';
}


startChr();
```

Comment: yes it's possible...what have you tried? Make an attempt and post your code

Comment: I have tried putting a normal stopwatch like this:

Comment: nevermind, its too long to post as a comment

Comment: post code in question

Comment: there, i posted the code

Answer (score 1):

You may want to make your period 1s then:

```
var UPDATE_PERIOD = 1;
var ACTION_PERIOD = 3 * UPDATE_PERIOD;

var passed = 0;
setInterval(function() {
  passed += UPDATE_PERIOD;

  updateTimer();
  if(passed % ACTION_PERIOD === 0) {
    doStuff();
  }
}, UPDATE_PERIOD * 1000);

function updateTimer() {
  document.getElementById("timer").textContent = "" + passed + "s";
}

function doStuff() {
  // do your stuff here
}
```

Very simple example: http://jsbin.com/aSAQiYud/1/edit

Comment: hey i tried this, and nothing showed up on my page, i tried a few different ways and nothing is working

Comment: I don't know what your HTML is, or what you are trying to accomplish in detail. The idea was to show you the general strategy. Is it clear to you what this code does? Do you need a more detailed explanation?

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/459Lt/

this is actually very easy. I used jquery but that's for just selecting elements. Nothing truly that controls logic.

`w.clone().appendTo('body');` is where you would like to put function that needs to be called... like `dowork()`.....

```
var t=0, w=$('.w'),txt=$('.text');

setInterval(f,1000);
function f(){
    txt.text(t+1); 
    if(t==2) w.clone().appendTo('body');
    t=++t%3;
}
```